# Star Trek interior plaques

Tags: font-identification, tv-series

I'm looking for the font found in Star Trek that most likely was routed onto plastic plaque boards during the 60s-70s in offices in general. It looked like the pic provided.

The closest my brother found was DIN Condensed (Rounded) but unfortunately the project Im working on has no budget at all so spending $50-300 for the font is out of the question. Does anyone have an alternative?

[image]

Comment: It's likely the letters on the machine that created the signs is not actually a font, since it was created prior to desktop publishing.

Comment: That's the block font (not condensed block) for a Hermes (or New Hermes, depending on the year) Engravograph, a mechanical pantograph for engraving; it used a router head for engraving plastics and a stylus for engraving metals. The modern electromechanical equivalents don't even offer the old fonts; they use Arial as a stand-in. If it's any help, you can get the brass font tiles on eBay cheaply, but it's a heck of a job trying to load them into your computer.

Answer (score 5):

That is a single stroke font. Meaning the letters are made up of open paths. It's made specifically to engrave using a bull nose or V-bit on a CNC or for a laser engraver.

They are usually included with the high end CAD/CAM programs.

You won't be able to use them in a typical application because ***most*** design programs have trouble rendering them and do not provide support for them.

Try [Orach Technic](http://www.e-engraving.com/fonts/One_Line_Fonts.htm) it's been known to work on Illustrator although I haven't tried it.
If you use Inkscape try [Hershey Text](http://www.evilmadscientist.com/2011/hershey-text-an-inkscape-extension-for-engraving-fonts/).

Good luck!

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)

Answer (score 0):

I tried finding it on WhatTheFont, didn't find anything.

You either have to ask on their forums (and it'll either be custom or expensive) or you can try to find an alternative with a similar style.

I found Dosis on a quick Google Fonts search, I'm sure you can find a lot more appropriate free typefaces.

Google Fonts (and its selection) and Typekit (and its good filters) will be the right places to look if you need decent free typefaces.

Here's Dosis by Impallari Type on Google Fonts: https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Dosis

[image: Dosis]