# OpenType Font Based On Lines Instead On Shapes

Tags: vector, font-design, opentype

Does the OpenType format support letters which not consist of closed shapes but only line segmets?  E.g. the capital I might consist of two horizontal and one vertical lines.

So if I want to use such a font in a vector graphics editor, I'd have to set a positive stroke width to make the letters visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at least no application reading the font will not be able to do so. Now if your aim is **not** to engrave the result then you can still do a a font without an area using the "I" as an example your font would have 12 interconnected lines.

Note that many engineering apps do support line fonts.

- Also read [wire-one-dimensional-font](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64618/wire-one-dimensional-font/)

Answer (score 0):

No, but Inkscap(dot)org has a Hershey Text extension you could use to generate single stroke lettering for engraving

It's pretty easy to use. In Inkscape click Extensions > Render > Hershey Text. Enter your text, choose the font face from those available, and hit Apply. The rendered text isn't editable as text. The extension only generates vectors.

[image]